# French M2 research internship as a UK MSc student?

Tags: research-process, masters, internship, france

I'm planning on starting a UK MSc degree in September, but keen to get some research experience abroad.

I'm wondering if anyone knows if French universities/research labs would be accepting of a candidate from a UK university for advertised positions for a M2 stage (2nd year Masters internship), considering that a student on a UK MSc will have only been studying on the programme for 6/7 months.

Any insight appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any particular obstruction for you to get accepted in an internship program for M2 students. The only legal requirement is that you are currently enrolled in an M2 program or equivalent. In our Master, the program starts in September and internships in February/March.